# Nopcommerce 4.2 custom plugin install issue

Tags: nopcommerce, nopcommerce-4.2

I'm not going to mention all the steps I tried before, so maybe someone can give me hint for the correct next steps:

1. Nopcommerce 4.2 source in a local VS2017 environment
2. Added my custom plugin project (no funtionality, just basic views etc)
3. App_data > plugins.json has no mention of my custom plugin (I think thats oke)
4. Run the solution in debug mode (NOP.web) with no issues
5. Configuration > Local Plugins lists my plugin name with logo and install button

What are the correct next steps to get it listed as installed?
The obvious answer (click install button, click restart button to apply changes) does not get it listed as installed.

Comment: The question is not clear to me, is you plugin not listed in the plugin list? or after installation, it was still not installed

Comment: It was listed, but after clicking install, stop debug and restart nop.web it didn't install. Solved already: the implementation code in the IPlugin interface had a typo which forsome reason didn't get reported in the log after install.

Comment: @Groot You can put debug pointer on `PluginService.InstallPlugins()` after apply changes (plugin is installed).